# Fourier series saw function coeficient expression

Tags: fourier-series

so im trying to apply the fourier series to a saw function and following this [website](http://www.thefouriertransform.com/series/sawExample.php)
and if you look at eq 2, i dont understand the last step, i tried solving it myself but the second term disapears over there... i got:$$c_n=\frac{A(\pi2ni+1)}{4\pi^2n^2}$$
is it because only the complex part is used?
and why isnt $c_0=0$?

Comment: the +1 in cn is wrong and shouldnt be there, it should be cancel by a $e^{i 2 \pi n}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 
$$
c_n = \frac1T \int_{0}^{T} f(t) e^{-i\frac{2\pi nt}{T}}dt \\
f(t) = \frac ATt
$$

Then

$$
c_0 = \frac1T \int_{0}^{T} f(t) dt = \frac1T [\frac{At^2}{2T} ]_{0}^{T} = \frac1T(\frac{AT}2) = \frac A2
$$

For $c_n$ you should get arrive at

$$
-Ae^{i2\pi n}\frac{-2i \pi n + e^{i 2 \pi n } -1 }{4\pi^2 n^2} = \frac{iA}{2\pi n}.
$$

Comment: ah right i forgot i should hav evaluated the integral for c0 before doing it... what about $c_n$? what am i missing?

Comment: I have updated my answer @wrong1man

Comment: oh god im stupid.. i forgot "the lower integral", i subsrituted "t=T" in, but i forgot to subtract with "t=0" dumb me... thank you!

Comment: the "i goes up" and the sign changes cause you multiply by $\frac{i}{i}$ correct?

Comment: Indeed. @wrong1man